# How to convert normal 256 color to video mode 13h color encoding?

Tags: window, dos, converters, bmp

I wonder how can I convert normal 256 color(create by windows paint)

to

dos vga 256 color.(used by mode 13h)

For instance, pure white color in vga 256 (mode 13h) is 0x0f in hex.

But pure white color made by windows paint is not 0x0f, but 0xff.

It's OK to lose quality.

It is too laborious to create every image file I want to use to 13h mode version by hand.

Answer (score 1):

You should either re-program the VGA palette to match the color table in the .bmp (this will cause no quality loss), or you can use a tool like photoshop to re-map the .bmp files to the standard VGA palette (which may cause quality loss, depending on the palette used in the .bmp).

Here's some example code I found on Google: http://www.brackeen.com/vga/bitmaps.html#2